# Set sheet location, resize and reposition charts in Excel

Tags: excel, vbscript, charts

I want to create a 3D pie chart in Excel.  Now, I have the code for creating it and setting the source data and what not but my issue is that I want the chart on a specific sheet and I want to resize it and reposition it.  I have tried various options I have found on the net from VBA examples to VBScript examples but nothing works.  My VBScript code is as follows:

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject( "Excel.Application" )
objExcel.Visible = True
objExcel.SheetsInNewWorkbook = 1
objExcel.Workbooks.Add
Set objSheet = objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets( 1 )

objSheet.Cells( 1, 1 ).Value = "Operating System"
objSheet.Cells( 2, 1 ).Value = "Windows Server 2003"
objSheet.Cells( 3, 1 ).Value = "Windows XP"
objSheet.Cells( 4, 1 ).Value = "Windows 2000"
objSheet.Cells( 5, 1 ).Value = "Windows NT 4.0"
objSheet.Cells( 6, 1 ).Value = "Other"

objSheet.Cells( 1, 2 ).Value = "Number of Computers"
objSheet.Cells( 2, 2 ).Value = 146
objSheet.Cells( 3, 2 ).Value = 487
objSheet.Cells( 4, 2 ).Value = 211
objSheet.Cells( 5, 2 ).Value = 41
objSheet.Cells( 6, 2 ).Value = 56

Set objRange = objSheet.UsedRange
objRange.Select
Set colCharts = objExcel.Charts
colCharts.Add()
Set objChart = colCharts( 1 )
objChart.Activate
objChart.ChartType = 70
objChart.Elevation = 40
objChart.Rotation = 80
```

I found the keywork `objChart.Location 1` but that creates the chart on its own sheet and it takes up the whole sheet.  I have tried 0 and 2 but both return errors.  I have also tried a sheet name but that also returns an error.  Then, once I have it on a sheet I want, I want to resize the whole chart and position it.

With setting the size and position I have found the following:

```
objExcel.ActiveChart.Width = 300
```

That generates an error though.  I found various type of the above line but all to no avail.  The above might work but I suspect that because the chart is on its own sheet and is being displayed in "full screen" mode it can't be resized / repositioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the chart to the worksheet. Change this:

```
Set objRange = objSheet.UsedRange
objRange.Select
Set colCharts = objExcel.Charts
colCharts.Add()
Set objChart = colCharts( 1 )
objChart.Activate
```

into this:

```
Set objRange = objSheet.UsedRange
objRange.Select
Set objChart = objSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(262, -4102)
objChart.Activate
```

Recording an action as a macro usually helps when you're stuck with how to do something in Excel.

Comment: Thanks.  I found a way to do it.  `Set objChart = objSheet.ChartObjects.Add( 50, 40, 350, 250 ).Chart` which seems to be a variation on what you suggested.